# Uploading .tif files to assets library is slow

Tags: picture-library, image-upload

I try to upload a bulk of `tif` files to a assets library.

The `tif` files are not large, but take a long time to upload. I think this is because SharePoint is generating a thumbnail for each new `tif` file. Is there some trick to make it faster to upload `tif` files? `.jpeg` and `pdf` files are going fast!

Comment: How the upload is being done?

Comment: programmatically, but I do not have access to the code. I was just wondering if this is an known issue. Or maybe someone know the best practice to upload tiff files programmatically.